# Detect scrolling control

Tags: ios, swift, scroll

I have 2 ViewCollection at ViewController and function

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

}
```

How can I detect which collection scrolling in current function ?

Comment: `if scrollView == self.collectionView1 { ... } else { ... }`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`UICollectionView` is just a subclass of `UIScrollView`. Just keep reference to your collectionViews, and you can check if the scrollview and the collectionview is equal.

So simply use the following code:

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if scrollView == self.collectionViewA {
            // do something with collectionViewA
        } else if scrollView == self.collectionViewB {
            // do something with collectionViewB
        } else {
            // unknown collectionView
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

I think this is better in Swift.

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    switch scrollView {
        case collectionViewA:
            // do something
        case collectionViewB:
            // do something
        default:
            break
    }
}
```